# Display an image when a task is selected

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want the tasks display a different image when one of them is checked.

For example, if I have three different tasks:

```
Task 1: Standard version
Task 2: Lite version
Task 3: Pro version
```

- when Task 1 is checked must display an image.
- when Task 2 is checked must hide Task 1 image and display Task 2 image.
- When Task 3 is checked must hide others below tasks image and show Task 3 image.

[image]

Here some code

```pascal
[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } { Don't remove this line! }
{ Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically. }
var
  BitmapImage1: TBitmapImage;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  { BitmapImage1 }
  BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with BitmapImage1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
    Left := ScaleX(320);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(57);
    Height := ScaleY(57);
    ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp');
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp'));
  end;

  with WizardForm.TasksList do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(257);
    Height := ScaleY(200);
    Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`WizardIsTaskSelected`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected) (`IsTaskSelected` in older versions of Inno Setup) to find out what tasks have been selected.
- Handle `WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck` and [`CurPageChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged) to detect selection change and update image accordingly.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "lite.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "pro.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "std.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Tasks]
Name: std; Description: "Standard version"; Flags: exclusive
Name: lite; Description: "Lite version"; Flags: exclusive
Name: pro; Description: "Pro version"; Flags: exclusive

[Code]
var
  BitmapImage1: TBitmapImage;

procedure UpdateTasksImage;
var
  Image: string;
begin
  if WizardIsTaskSelected('pro') then Image := 'pro.bmp'
    else
  if WizardIsTaskSelected('lite') then Image := 'lite.bmp'
    else
  if WizardIsTaskSelected('std') then Image := 'std.bmp'
    else Image := '';

  if Image <> '' then
  begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile(Image); 
    BitmapImage1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + Image));
    BitmapImage1.Visible := True;
  end
    else
  begin
    BitmapImage1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Update image, when task selection changes }
  UpdateTasksImage;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  { Update image, when task page is entered }
  { (as tasks can be selected by changing setup type or components) }
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    UpdateTasksImage;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with BitmapImage1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
    Left := ScaleX(320);
    Top := ScaleY(88);
    Width := ScaleX(57);
    Height := ScaleY(57);
  end;

  with WizardForm.TasksList do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(257);
    Height := ScaleY(200);
  end;

  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck
end;
```

[image]

[image]

---

Though it seems to me, that your "tasks" should actually be setup types or components. It does not make sense to me, that a user can select *combinations* of "standard", "lite" and "pro". Shouldn't those be a *distinct* options?

Comment: Yes if one of them is checked the others two must be uncheckd.

Comment: So why do you show checkboxes in your question? Those should be radio buttons. And again, then these are not tasks, but setup types or components.

Comment: Anyway, I've answered your question.

Comment: So in this part what Dir should i use for: 'pro.bmp'?  |'{app}\pro.bmp'|?

Comment: What "this part"?

Comment: `begin
  if IsTaskSelected('pro') then Image := 'pro.bmp'
    else
  if IsTaskSelected('lite') then Image := 'lite.bmp'
    else
  if IsTaskSelected('std') then Image := 'std.bmp'
    else Image := '';`

Comment: That's not a path, that's only a file name. Leave it as it is - The code works like shown, no modifications are needed.

Comment: Mine is not displaying pro, lite and std images, see this image: http://imgur.com/a/Rmw6j

Comment: Because you load the same image every time (`BitmapImage1.bmp`). You are not using the `Image` variable. Use my code as is.

Answer (score 0):

Add **OnClickCheck** event :
Eg:

```
var
  BitmapImage1: TBitmapImage;
  BitmapImage2: TBitmapImage;
  BitmapImage3: TBitmapImage;

procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[0] = True) then
    begin
      BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
      with BitmapImage1 do
      begin
        Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
        Left := ScaleX(320);
        Top := ScaleY(88);
        Width := ScaleX(57);
        Height := ScaleY(57); 

        ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp');        
   Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp'));
      end;
    end;

    if (WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[1] = True) then
    begin
      BitmapImage2 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
      with BitmapImage1 do
      begin
        Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
        Left := ScaleX(320);
        Top := ScaleY(88);
        Width := ScaleX(57);
        Height := ScaleY(57);
        ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.BitmapImage2.bmp');        
   Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.BitmapImage2.bmp'));
      end;
    end;
    if (WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[2] = True) then
    begin
      BitmapImage3 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
      with BitmapImage1 do
      begin
        Parent := WizardForm.SelectTasksPage;
        Left := ScaleX(320);
        Top := ScaleY(88);
        Width := ScaleX(57);
        Height := ScaleY(57);
        ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.BitmapImage3.bmp');        
   Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.BitmapImage3.bmp'));
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin        
    WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck

    with WizardForm.TasksList do
    begin
      Width := ScaleX(257);
      Height := ScaleY(200);
      Visible := True;
    end;
end;
```